# How to change simple_form to use bootstrap prepended inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I'm use Rails 3.2, simple_form and it's default bootstrap generator.

I want to use one of the Bootstrap "appended and prepended" form elements in my layout. How do I modify the simple form input to generate the needed code?

**Code used**:
`<%= f.input :price, :label => 'Price:' %>`

**Generated code**:

```
<div class="control-group string optional">
    <label class="string optional" for="price">Price:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input class="string optional" id="price" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Desired Code**:

```
<div class="control-group string optional">
    <label class="string optional control-label" for="price">Price:</label>
    <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on">$</span>
        <input class="string optional" id="price" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

Note the "input-prepend" class change and the "add-on" span.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a wrapper.

For pre-append the code is something like this:

```
 <%= f.input :price, :wrapper => :prepend, :label => false do %>
    <%= content_tag :span, "$", :class => "add-on" %>
    <%= f.input_field :price %>
  <% end %>
```

For more information check this [live example](http://simple-form-bootstrap.plataformatec.com.br/articles/new) of using simple_form with bootstrap. You can find the code [here](https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap/blob/master/app/views/articles/_form.html.erb).

Hope it help.

Comment: I had to modify `config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb` and change `input-prepend` and `input-append` to `input-group` in order to make it work.

Comment: Consider that my solution is for bootstrap 2, if you need support for bootstrap 3 you should modify the simple_form initializer as @guyaloni